# How do I know the credentials by which I SSH into my Linode VPS?

Tags: ssh, vps, linode

I have been handed a user/pass to login into the web-based front end on linode.com but this user/pass doesn't work for SSH.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should create your own users and passwords in the web interface and login with those.

Answer (score 1):

Log into your linode control panel. Click on the Linode you wish to access. Shut down the server using button on right side. Then click "Settings & Utilities" and fill in the new root password details bottom left. Start up server again and then try root@newpassword!